# Word list search with hashmap in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, hashmap

I have a word list and there are more than 50,000 words in my word list. As you can see, I read my words and add them to an Array List, but after this process, when I want to read my words, it happens very slowly. That's why `Hashmap` came to my mind. I want to read my words and when I receive a word input from the user, I want to have it checked whether it is in the `HashMap`. Even though I did research, I could not find how to do it exactly. How can I do this?

```
  public ArrayList<String> wordReader () throws FileNotFoundException {
        File txt = new File(path);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
        ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scanner.nextLine();
            words.add(data);
        }
        scanner.close();
        return words;
    }
```

Comment: What specific issue are you having? Hash lookup is a single method call.

Comment: Please share the code relative to HashMap that you tried. As it seems you have no value to put in the map, a HashSet would seems nice

Comment: Why do you want to check if it is the map?  What action will you take if it is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you're having performance issues in traversing an `ArrayList` filled with 50.000 words when you're trying to check if a specific word exists in your list or not.

This is because looking for an element in an unsorted `List` has **O(n)** complexity. You could improve the performances by employing a sorted data structure like a BST (a Binary Search Tree) which will improve the research operation with a **O(log n)** complexity.

Also, your idea of using a `Map` is definitely viable, since a `HashMap` grants a complexity for add and get operations between **O(1)** (for theoretically perfect hashing algorithm with no collisions at all among the keys) and **O(n)** (for bad hashing algorithms with a high chance of collision). Besides, since Java 8, it has been introduced an optimization in the `HashMap` implementation, where under high collision conditions with multiple elements added to the same bucket, the data structure corresponding to a bucket is actually implemented as a Balanced Tree rather than a list, granting a **O(log n)** complexity in the worst case.

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-collections/java-map-cheatsheet.html

However, using a `HashMap` for what I assume is a dictionary (only distinct words) could be unnecessary, since you would use a word as both a key and a value. Instead of a `HashMap`, you could use a `Set` as others have pointed out, or better a `HashSet`. As in fact, a `HashSet` is implemented via a `HashMap` instance under the hood, which will give us all the performance and advantages previously discussed (this is why I wrote that preface).

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html

Your implementation could look like this:

```
public Set<String> wordReader(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File txt = new File(path);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = scanner.nextLine();
        words.add(data);
    }
    scanner.close();
    return words;
}

public boolean isWordContained(Set<String> set, String word) {
    return set.contains(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Set`, not a `List` since sets automatically ignore duplicates when you add them to the set.  If it wasn't present it returns true and adds it, otherwise false.

```
public Set<String> wordReader () throws FileNotFoundException {
        File txt = new File(path);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
        Set <String> words = new HashSet<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scanner.nextLine();
            if(!words.add(data)) {
               // present - Do something
            } 
         }   
        
        scanner.close();
        return words;
}
```

- because sets are not ordered they are not random access collections. So you can add the set to a list as follows:

```
Set<String> words = wordReader();
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>(words);
```

Now you can retrieve them with an index.

- you may want to make your method more versatile by passing the file name as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be checking whether the word input is present in your list of words read from the file, you can use a `HashSet<String>` instead of using an `ArrayList<String>`.

Your method would then become

```
public HashSet<String> wordReader () throws FileNotFoundException {
        File txt = new File(path);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
        HashSet <String> words = new HashSet<String>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scanner.nextLine();
            words.add(data);
        }
        scanner.close();
        return words;
    }
```

Now after you read the word input, you can check whether it is present in the `HashSet`. This would be a much faster operation as lookup would take constant time.

```
public boolean isWordPresent(String word, HashMap<String> words){
    return words.contains(word);
}
```

As a side note, `HashSet` internally uses a `HashMap` to perform the operations.